# Estimating the probability that a coin drawn at random will land on Heads

Tags: probability, estimation

Suppose we have a large pool of biased coins with different Heads-probability; the Heads-probability is a random variable with some complicated distribution (e.g. truncated normal). We want to estimate the probability that, if we draw a coin at random and toss it, it will land on Heads. I consider the following three experiments:

- Draw $n$ coins; toss each coin $m$ times; count the number of Heads and divide by $m n$.
- Draw $m n$ coins; toss each coin one time; count the number of Heads and divide by $m n$.
- Draw $1$ coin; toss it $m n$ times; count the number of Heads and divide by $m n$.

Note: the pool is much larger than $m n$, so the fact that we draw $m n$ coins does not change the distribution (alternatively, we can draw a coin $m n$ times with replacement).

Are these experiments equivalent? If not, which of them would give a better estimate of the actual probability?

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: @Tim no... I am too old for homework. It is a question that arised in a research project in voting theory.

Comment: I’m asking because the last option is so obviously bad, that it sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: Why not $mn$ times draw with replacement a coin and toss it once?

Comment: Are you at all interested in estimating a particular coins bias, or are you just interested in the probability of a head?

Comment: @Tim drawing $m n$ times with replacement is what I meant in the second option. Alternatively, we can just assume that the pool is so large (relative to $m n$) that drawing $m n$ coins does not change the probability.

Comment: @DemetriPananos No particular coins - only the apriori probability of a head.

Comment: I think Tim is right then.  Draw some coins, flip them once, estimate P(Heads) as # heads / # coins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three of your methods are unbiased estimators of the mean, but have different variances:

- Drawing  $m n$ coins and tossing each coin one time has the smallest variance
- Drawing $n$ coins and tossing each coin $m$ times has a variance between the other two
- Drawing  $1$ coin and tossing  it $m n$ times has the greatest variance

so in a sense drawing  $m n$ coins is the best of these options if you want to estimate the probability that, if we draw a coin at random and toss it, it will land on Heads.

The middle option might give you a better idea of the shape of the overall distribution, but that is not the question you asked.

(Another unbiased method would be drawing one coin and tossing it once.  This would have an even higher variance.)

Comment: It'd be great if you could actually prove how they differ in variance and that they are unbiased.

Comment: @Tim -  drawing one coin and tossing it once is unbiased - its expectation conditioned on being that coin is $p$ for that coin, and so its unconditional expectation is the mean of the distribution.  The three bulleted cases are then unbiased by linearity of expectation.  The variances can be found by the law of total variance